# Regex.Replace not working

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a strange issue with Regex.Replace

```
string test = "if the other party is in material breach of such contract and, after <span style=\"background-color:#ffff00;\">forty-five (45)</span> calendar days notice of such breach";
string final = Regex.Replace(test, "forty-five (45)", "forty-five (46)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

the "final" string still shows "forty-five (45)". Any idea why? I am assuming it has to do something with the  tag. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: Did you really want to replace *forty-five (45)* with *forty-five (46)*?  Looks like a typo.

Comment: I am assuming it is because of the special characters "(" and ")"

Comment: @ErikPhilips, this is just a test text. I know the text does not make sense but this is just a test scenario which is failing.

Comment: I tried String.Replace() and that fixed my issue. But I would still like to know how can I get it working with Regex.

Comment: Don't forget [the dangers of parsing html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/781965)

Answer (score 6):

Escape the parenthesis. Depending on the language, might require two back slashes.

```
string final = Regex.Replace(test, "forty-five \(45\)", "forty-five (46)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Basically, parenthesis are defined to mean something, and by escaping the characters, you are telling regex to use the parenthesis character, and not the meaning.

Better yet, why are you using a Regex to do this at all? Try just doing a normal [string replacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string final = test.Replace("forty-five (45)", "forty-six (46)")
```

Comment: I actually simplified the code for posting. The  "search" and "replace" variables are dynamic. So I can't really escape anything.

Comment: Why can't you escape ( and )?  Those can be string replaced before regex replaced.

Comment: @ErikPhilips the actual string might contain other special characters as well. So it won't be feasible to check on each special character.

Comment: If that's the case, you probably want to do a replacement that doesn't involve regex. See my edit.

Comment: It seems you don't have a clear understanding (or you haven't communicated it) of what your source and replacement values are.  [Escaping special characters isn't that hard, I don't see the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses are special in regular expressions. They delimit a *group*, to allow for things such as alternation. For example, the regular expression `foo(bar|bat)baz` matches:

- `foo`, followed by
- either `bar` OR `bat`, followed by
- `baz`

So, a regular expression like `foo(bar)` will never match the literal string `foo(bar)`. What it will match is the literal string `foobar`. Consequently, you need to escape the metacharacters. In C#, this should do you:

```
string final = Regex.Replace(test, @"forty-five \(45\)", "forty-five (46)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The @-quoted string helps avoid headaches from excessive backslashes. Without it, you'd have to write "forty-five \(45\)".

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to escape the parenthesis, put them in a character class:

`forty-five [(]45[)]`